# tput cols doesn't work properly in a script

Tags: bash

I'm using `tput cols` in a script everything goes OK except when the windows is maximized.

My script is able to get any windows size correctly but when the windows is maximized, it gets a wrong value (80).

Then I type `tput cols` directly into the terminal and I get the correct size (158).

So my question is, how can I get the right value even when the window is maximized?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which terminal emulator?

Answer (score 4):

`tput cols` may be reading from the shell environment variable `$COLUMNS` instead of the `TIOCGWINSZ` ioctl.  The shell is probably updating this variable in response to `SIGWINCH`, but this of course does not affect the `$COLUMNS` variable within your script.

Try `unset COLUMNS` and seeing if `tput cols` picks up the value from the terminal ioctl.

Comment: tput cols picks up the right value after unsetting COLUMNS. How can I use SIGWINCH in my script?

Comment: Something like `trap 'COLUMNS=$(COLUMNS= tput cols)' SIGWINCH` I suppose, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do that.

Comment: I just want to get the width of the window :-( but 
"tput cols" doesn't work when the windows is maximized

Answer (score 2):

First of all run:

```
$ shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Try to use `resize` as command in order to get informations about. You will get the values you need. In order to use them in your program, you could just write something like this:

```
echo "Old value of COLUMNS: $COLUMNS"
# This should execute the output of resize and export the var you need
eval $(resize)
echo "New value of COLUMNS: $COLUMNS"
```

For more informations about resize look at `man resize` or check this link: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html

Comment: I had to add `eval $(resize)` if I set `exec 2>>file` in a Bash script to get `tput cols` and `tput lines` display correct value. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

For a similar issue in bash, when I was doing an

```
# X is a script that uses 'tput cols'
$(eval X)
```

... it was reverting back to 80 columns.

So, I changed my eval to:

```
T=`tput cols` 
$(COLUMNS=$T X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the *columns* and *lines* information in the following way, instead:

```bash
cols=$(stty size | awk '{print $2}')
lines=$(stty size | awk '{print $1}')
```