# SIGWINCH, bash, dash, tput, and terminfo

Tags: ncurses, terminfo, tput

I'm a little confused about the interaction between `tput` and terminal sizes.  It seems that the behavior of `tput` depends on the shell under which it is invoked, or perhaps the shell is responsible for changing terminal settings, or.... something.  To reduce the problem, consider:

```
dash$ exec bash
bash$ trap 'echo winched' WINCH
bash$ tput cols
176
bash$ # changing terminal size now (after hitting return)
bash$ winched
bash$ winched
tput cols
150
bash$ exec dash
dash$ trap 'echo winched' WINCH
dash$ tput cols
150
dash$ # changing terminal size now (after hitting return)
dash$ tput cols
winched
150
```

Here, in bash, things behave (almost) as expected (I say almost, because I'm not quite sure why the WINCH handler executes twice), and the output of `tput` changes to match the new terminal size.  However, when running in dash, the `tput` output does not change even though the terminal has changed size.  Also note that the WINCH handler seems to be delayed by dash, and does not execute until after the next command is entered (but before it executes).   What is supposed to happen here?  Does `tput` in any way care about what the shell is doing?  Is the WINCH at all relevant?  I suppose the question is:

How does `tput` know the size of the terminal?

Also, I didn't want to clutter up the output too much, but in each shell of the example, TERM is set and `infocmp $TERM` prints terminfo descriptions that seem valid. (The fact that it gives any output, I think, indicates it is valid data!)

Comment: Yikes.  `tput -T$TERM` seems to just repot `80` regardless of the terminal size.  That is, it just blindly reports the value of $COLUMNS, and dash is not updating COLUMNS.  So what is the point of `tput cols`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious from the description:

> `-T`*type*
>   
>    indicates the type of terminal.  Normally this option is  unnecessary,  because the default is taken from the environment variable **`TERM`**.  If **`-T`** is specified, then the shell  variables  **`LINES`**
>   and **`COLUMNS`** will also be ignored.

but [**current**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/26de29e6bf54603c615d10077f526e70c0f75848/NEWS#L1159) **`tput`** calls [`use_env`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env) and [`use_tioctl`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_tioctl) for the **`-T`** option:

```
20171007
    + modify "-T" option of clear and tput to call use_tioctl() to obtain
      the operating system's notion of the screensize if possible.
```

The **`tput`** manual page has a section *[Terminal Size](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h3-Terminal-Size)*, which goes into more detail.

This example (using ncurses 6.1) works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "resize; tput cols; tput -T$TERM cols" WINCH

while true
do
        sleep 1
done
```

With ncurses 6.0, you would see that difference.  With other implementations, *ymmv*.

Regarding *bash*, that was discussed a while back: *[tput cols doesn't work properly in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308166/tput-cols-doesnt-work-properly-in-a-script)* (but that q/a doesn't have any relevance to the `-T` option).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I still  don't really understand the desired sequence of events.  Is it supposed to be: windows changes size, shell receives SIGWINCH, shell makes an ioctl to determine window size, shell updates COLUMNS, subsequent calls to tput in that shell get value from COLUMNS.  If that is correct, then this behavior is a a dash bug, no?

Comment: Or, more practically, is a program that uses ncurses supposed to delete all windows and recreate in response to a SIGWINCH?

Comment: With ncurses, a program can resize the windows; with older curses, it could delete and recreate the windows (which makes more repainting than ncurses).